# Malicious file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hi and thank you for looking at my question.

I have found a strange JS that is being loaded into my website, it refers to typekit but this file is not being loaded on my testing site and has a strange name, I might be paranoid but we have been under attack for the last 2 months.

The file name is: kho3rsd.js
Request URL: https://use.typekit.net/kho3rsd.js

I tried searching for any information regarding this file name but nothing comes up.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks as if it's a font, does that seem feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very safe and normal script that loads a certain font from the website. It's minified, have random name and built for performance reasons.

And this probably has no relation to the attack to your website.